# checking integer overflow in python

Tags: python

```
class Solution(object):
    def reverse(self, x):
        """
        :type x: int
        :rtype: int
        """
        negative = False
        if(x < 0):
            x = x * -1
            negative = True
        else:
            x = x
        sum = 0
        dig = 1
        strX = str(x)
        lst = list(strX)
        for i in lst:
            sum += int(i) * dig
            dig *= 10

        if(abs(sum) > 2 ** 32):
            return 0
        elif(negative == True):
            return sum * -1
        else:
            return sum
```

This is a leetcode problem that asks us to reverse an integer. I know it's a dirty code but it still works but it does not return 0 when the reversed integer overflows. I tried to check that on the line

```
        if(abs(sum) > 2 ** 32):
            return 0
```

but one of the test cases gives me:

```
Input: 1563847412
```

---

```
Output: 2147483651
```

---

```
Expected: 0
```

First, I am not sure why this overflows, and I am not sure how to fix this.

Thanks!

Comment: The largest 32-bit signed integer is `(1 << 31) - 1`, which is 2147483647.

Comment: Assuming you're checking for signed integers, you need `abs(sum) > 2 ** 31 - 1` (or, even better, `abs(sum) > (1 << 31) - 1`)

Comment: This code is a lot more complicated than it needs to be. For instance, you can reverse a string in a single step, you don't need a `for` loop to do it. BTW, it's not a good idea to use `sum` as a variable name because that shadows the built-in `sum` function. It won't hurt anything here, though.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

change `if(abs(sum) > 2 ** 32):` to `if(abs(sum) > (2 ** 31 - 1)):` or `abs(sum) > (1 << 31) - 1):` The largest 32 bit signed interger is actually not 2^32 but (2 ^ (31)) -1). because we need **one bit reserve as the sign bit.**

Read about it [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2,147,483,647) of why The number 2,147,483,647 (or hexadecimal 7FFF,FFFF) is the maximum positive value for a 32-bit signed binary integer

Comment: I think down voter should provide justification why?

Comment: seems like someone upvoted my answer. But I still wish whoever downvoted it can give an explanation.

Comment: Yeah who downvoted? I selected your answer. Thanks for the explanation!

Comment: @OLIVER.KOO I understand reserving 1 bit as the sign bit, so it's not to the power of 32 but rather 31. But can you explain why is it "minus 1"? Why is it not (2**31)? Thanks!

Comment: I think the smallest 32-bit signed integer is - 2 ** 31

Comment: @SAKURA because  signed 32 bit integer range is  [-2147483648 to 2147483647]. So negative it's 2**31 and positive is 2**31-1

Answer (score 3):

I guess some thing light weight like below could perhaps achieve the same logic, For someone else looking , the main overflow check after reversed 32 bit int is

```
if(abs(n) > (2 ** 31 - 1)):
                    return 0
```

Full code below

```
def reverse(self, x):

            neg = False
            if x < 0:
                neg = True
                x = x * -1

            s = str(x)[::-1]
            n = int(s)
            if neg:
                n = n*-1
            if(abs(n) > (2 ** 31 - 1)):
                return 0
            return n
```

Comment: @ErikvonAsmuth ok fixed

Answer (score 1):

The largest 32-bit signed integer is `(1 << 31) - 1` which is `(2**31)-1` but not `(2**32)`.

Try This way :

```
class Solution(object):
  def reverse(self, x):
    """
    :type x: int
    :rtype: int
    """
    negative = False
    if (x < 0):
      x = x * -1
      negative = True
    else:
      x = x
    sum = 0
    dig = 1
    strX = str(x)
    lst = list(strX)
    for i in lst:
      sum += int(i) * dig
      dig *= 10

    if (abs(sum) > ((1 << 31) - 1)): #use (1 << 31) - 1) instead of 2 ** 32
      return 0
    elif (negative == True):
      return sum * -1
    else:
      return sum

if __name__ == '__main__':
    x = 1563847412
    sol = Solution().reverse(x)
    print(sol)
```

**Output :**

```
0
```

Answer (score 1):

```
class Solution:
    def reverse(self, x: int) -> int:

        split = [i for i in str(x)]
        split = split[::-1]
        final = ''

        
        if split[-1]=='-':
            final += '-'
            
            for i in split[0:-1]:
                print(i)
                final+=i
        else:
            
            for i in split[0:]:
                final+=i
                
        final = int(final)
        
        if(abs(final) > (2 ** 31 - 1)):
                return 0
                
        return(final)
```

Answer (score 0):

you can simply use:

```
if sum >= pow(2,31)-1:
     return 0
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if sum > ((1 << 31) - 1):
    return 0
else:
    if negative == True:
      sum = -sum
      return sum
```